# Problem with stripe react native apple pay

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm a bit desperate I haven't been able to integrate apple pay, first I'm not using expo and in the documentation it says that I need xcode that I couldn't use, and second I don't know if it's mandatory, can someone help me?

hello friends, I'm a bit desperate I haven't been able to integrate apple pay, first I'm not using expo and in the documentation it says that I need xcode that I couldn't use, and second I don't know if it's mandatory, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need Xcode to configure ApplePay's Merchant ID and certificate per [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=react-native). And yes it's mandatory. Please read the Stripe Doc above and follow step by step.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can pass my react native expo project to native code to do this stripe configuration, and then return my project to expo management mode to continue managing it from there? Thank you so much –

Answer (score 0):

```
  YES, Need to Add Apple Pay capability to your appfor Apple pay that 
  requires you to make changes to your Xcode project settings.This is 
  because Xcode is the primary development environment for building iOS 
  apps, and it provides tools and features for managing your app's 
  capabilities and configurations.
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I can pass my react native expo project to native code to do this stripe configuration, and then return my project to expo management mode to continue managing it from there? Thank you so much